# Disadvantages of using `std::wstring` for Unicode in cross-platform code?

Tags: c++, c++14, cross-platform, unicode-string, wstring

### Situation

I have a large existing Win32 C++ code-base, and I want to make it portable so that it compiles and runs on both Windows (MSCV) and Linux (gcc).

For a new project I would try to go [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), but this existing code-base already stores and processes its text in `std::wstring` as UTF-16.
So I expect to cause less upheaval, and have less risk of breaking existing behavior on Windows, if I keep it that way and try to work with it.

### Plan

So this is what text handling would look like once the code-base is cross-platform:

- Use std::wstring for storing text in memory, and operate on it using standard library functionality that accepts `std::wstring`/`wchar_t`.
- On Windows, this means UTF-16 (with 2 bytes per code unit).
- On Linux, this means UTF-32 (with 4 bytes per code unit).
- On the program's input/output boundaries, when text must be converted to/from other encodings, have `#ifdef`s to do the correct thing on both platforms.

### Question

**What are the downsides/problems of this approach?**

### Already considered

Problems I already considered:

- Higher memory usage compared to UTF-8.
- Per-code-unit processing like `std::tolower` will behave differently on the two platforms if there are Unicode codepoints outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).
- Some `std::wstring`-accepting overloads used by the current code-base, such as the `std::ifstream(std::wstring, ...)` constructor, are actually Microsoft-specific extensions and not available on Linux/GCC - so extra platform-specific `#ifdef`s will be necessary in those places.

But aside from that?

Comment: Well, this is going to get closed as opinion-based, but _have `#ifdefs` to do the correct thing on both platforms_ I would try to avoid that.  Instead, call a function which you implement differently on each platform that does the right thing for that platform.  Similarly, I would replace calls to `std::ifstream(std::wstring, ...)` with a function that constructs an `ifstream` from a `wstring`, thus, once again, abstracting the problem away and localising the platform-specific code in one place.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a `String` that accepts both `std::string`s and `std::wstring`s, but stores UTF-8 strings. Add `operator std::string& ()` and `operator std::wstring& ()` (+ `const` overloads) to make it easy to integrate it with existing functions.

Comment: PS: `std::tolower` is not a good way to lowercase a Unicode character

Comment: If you want portability, and UTF, I suggest using ICU: https://icu.unicode.org/

Comment: Consider using `std::u16string` and/or `std::u32string` instead of `std::wstring`. They will give you a more consistent interface across platforms (however, standard library functions have less support for them right now). As for using strings with `std::ifstream`, consider using `std::filesystem::path` instead to handle file paths in a cross-platform manner.